# Why is the php category missing in netbeans project creation dialog?

Tags: php, windows, netbeans

[image: Screenshot]

The PHP folder is missing, as you can see in the screenshot. I am using NetBeans 8.0.1. I have re-installed multiple times, and I have Xampp installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
your solution is

1. Go to Tools and select plugins
2. Click available plugins and search for php
3. select phpdocumentor2 and install it
4. select restart IDE Now and finish
   So 
   if you will select new project then you can see it
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Go Tools, plugins, Settings tab, activate updates. Then go to the "Available plugins" tab and reload the catalogue. Boom.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you please give me some more details?

Comment: Ok, there is no settings section. Do you mean options?

Comment: then make sure your thing is updating and the boxes are checked and stuff

Comment: then available plugins, check for newest, search for php

Comment: Php was selected in the installed tab, so I disabled it, restarted netbeans, and re enabled it. Still not working.

Comment: Did you verify that PHP works on your machine? load up a quick phpinfo() or something?

Comment: I was able to load a phpinfo from XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and select PHP folder

Afterwards, you should see the php folder when creating new pages.